# How to get an excel formula to parse a range as a single cell

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I type the following formula into the cell A1:

```
=B:B + C:C
```

Then if B and C are columns containing numbers, the value that will appear in A1 is B1 + C1. Now, suppose I type the following in my VBA editor:

```
Public Function MySum(x, y)
    MySum = x + y
End Function
```

Then the following will return a #VALUE! error:

```
=MySum(B:B,C:C)
```

But, for example, the following will work:

```
=MySum(B:B+0,C:C+0)
```

Excel will try evaluating B:B+0, realize that B:B should refer to the cell B1 and not the entire range, and perform the correct computation.

Is there any way of changing the code of MySum so MySum(B:B,C:C) will give the same result as B:B + C:C?

Comment: This is implicit intersection. Doing some quick research... [here](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/10/03/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-14-handling-whole-columns-using-implicit-intersection/) it is implemented in VBA but it seems to be a non-trivial effort. Best to just pass the UDF the actual ranges you want to work with.

Comment: Implicit intersection is, IMO, a bad habit to get into.

Comment: @JvdV I want to define columns as named ranges. For example, B:B might be named "cost_of_lemons" and C:C might be named "cost_of_sugar", then I want column A to be total cost = cost_of_lemons + cost_of_sugar

Comment: Another option - just use a table (Ctrl+T)?

Comment: What about one more parameter as a row > `Public Function MySum(x As Range, y As Range, rw As Long)`, then use `Row()` as the parameter's value when you call the function > `MySum = Intersect(x, Rows(rw)) + Intersect(y, Rows(rw))`. But a table is probably better.